# Unintuitive behavior of overloaded explicit constructors

Tags: c++, g++, 32bit-64bit

The following code compiles warning-less on a 64-bit Linux system using (native 64-bit) g++-10:

```
#include <cstdint>

class A {
  public:
    explicit A(unsigned long long int x) { };
    explicit A(uint64_t x) { };
};

int main() {}
```

However, on a 32-bit system, (same Linux distro, same version, but it is a 32-bit machine), I get this error:

```
t.cc:6:14: error: ‘A::A(uint64_t)’ cannot be overloaded with ‘A::A(long long unsigned int)’
    6 |     explicit A(uint64_t x) { };
      |              ^
t.cc:5:14: note: previous declaration ‘A::A(long long unsigned int)’
    5 |     explicit A(unsigned long long int x) { };
```

I tested the bitsizes experimentally (printf-ing `sizeof(long long unsigned int)`), and yes they are all 8 byte long on both 32 and 64 bit systems.

Why it then does not compile on a 32-bit system?

Extension:

I hunted a little bit for that, and I found in the glibc headers `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h` (or `/usr/include/i386-linux/bits/types.h`) that their defition differs by an `__extension__` macro or attribute:

```
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef signed long int __int64_t;
typedef unsigned long int __uint64_t;
#else
__extension__ typedef signed long long int __int64_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned long long int __uint64_t;
#endif
```

I think this `__extension__` is the important thing. If `__WORDSIZE == 64`, thus we are on a 64-bit environment, then these types are compatible. If not, then the type definitions differ by an `__extension__`. Where is this attribute (macro) from? How to make fair platform-independent code?

Comment: You might want to conditionally compile in the second constructor only if `std::uint64_t` is not implemented as an `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I hunted a little bit for that, and I found in the glibc headers `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h` (or `/usr/include/i386-linux/bits/types.h`) that their defition differs by an `__extension__` macro or attribute. I extend it into the question.

Comment: Do note that they don't just differ by `__extension__`.  If `WORDSIZE` is 64, then typedef unsigned long int __uint64_t; defines `uint64_t`.  Otherwise `typedef unsigned long long int __uint64_t;` defines `uint64_t`.  That's the part that's causing your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`uint64_t` is not a fundamental type.  It is an optional "type" that is an alias to a unsigned integer type that is 64 bits wide.  On your 32 bit system, that means most likely that they have it defined like

```
using uint64_t = unsigned long long int;
```

so they are they same type, and you can't have two overloads with the same signature

On your 64 bit machine, most likely they use `unsigned long int` instead since that is 64 bits on 64 bit linux distros.  That's why it works for 64 bits but not 32 bits.